# Animations in SVGs set as background-image are not playing on first page load in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, safari, svg-animate

If I add new `<div>` dynamically which has a CSS class set THAT has an animated SVG as the `background-image` it's animation never gets played on first page load in FireFox and Safari. This only happens when the cache is clear, on the second load it works. Is this a known Browser Bug? If so, what's the workaround?

Comment: Does this still fail in Firefox 35 (Aurora) or 36 (Beta). It could be something I've already fixed in Firefox. If not can you provide a testcase?

Comment: @RobertLongson this is Firefox 34.0.5, MacOSX Yosemite

Comment: OK, but that doesn't address the questions I asked.